# How to show that the curves $r=a(1+cosθ)$ and $r=b(1-cosθ)$ cut orthogonally?

Tags: calculus, curves

I tried to do the math by multiplying derivatives with respect to r and theta of both equation and then adding it. But I am not getting zero as expected. I think my method is wrong then.

Comment: You should post the work that you did, especially if you aren't getting the result you expected. This can allow others to find your mistake, which might be as simple as a sign error, without wasting anyone's time telling you things you already know.

Comment: Generalization of the following question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035228

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that two cardioids $r=a(1+\cos\theta)$ and $r=a(1-\cos\theta)$ are at right angles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3035228/show-that-two-cardioids-r-a1-cos-theta-and-r-a1-cos-theta-are-at-right)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have calculated $\frac{dr_1}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{dr_2}{d\theta}$ and then tried to multiple these two values together to get -1 like would normally be done in rectangular coordinates.

Note that $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ is the rate of change or $r$ with respect to $\theta$ and is not the gradient of the curve.

You want $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Recall that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ or: $x=f(\theta)cos\theta$ and $y=f(\theta)sin\theta$. Calculating derivatives gives:

$$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=f'(\theta)\cos\theta-f(\theta)\sin\theta=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta$$

$$\frac{dy}{d\theta}=f'(\theta)\sin\theta+f(\theta)\cos\theta=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta$$

Combining to get $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$ gives:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}$$

You could now divide top and bottom by $\cos\theta$ to write it using $tan\theta$ if you wanted to express it differently.

Comment: Taking this a bit further ... Since perpendicular lines have negative-reciprocal slopes, we want (for polar functions $r$ and $s$) $$\frac{r^\prime\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{r^\prime\cos\theta-r\sin\theta} = -\frac{s^\prime \cos\theta-s\sin\theta}{s^\prime\sin\theta+s\cos\theta}$$ Cross-multiplying and simplifying gives this simple characterization of orthogonal polar curves:
$$r^\prime s^\prime+r s = 0$$
This *may be* what OP has tried —the description of the work done vaguely matches— so it could be that OP made a relatively-simple error in differentiation and/or algebra.

Comment: @Blue Excellent point. I too was confused by exactly what OP had done/was doing.

Comment: @Ian Miller Hi Ian. A particular case of this question was asked and answered here : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035248 with an answer of mine based on conformal transformation $z \to z^2$.

Comment: @Ian Miller This is not strictly speaking a duplicate, because here coefficients $a$ and $b$ are different.