# Are subnormal and polar subnormal equal?

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, elliptic-functions

I have been studying Jacobi Elliptic functions and I am trying to understand the proof that the curve which ellipse describes is of the form $dn(x)$.I found this proof:

[image]

Where there is written $MG = - \frac{dr}{d\theta} = - y \frac{dy}{dx}$ this are supposed to be subnormal and polar subnormal. Now in polar coordinates $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{r’\sin{\theta} + r\cos{\theta}}{r’\cos{\theta} - r\sin{\theta}}$ however I could not figure out why is $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = y \frac{dy}{dx}$ true since definition of subnormal and polar subnormal are different so it must be true in this particular set up. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show that

$$MG=-r' \tag{1}$$

(with notation $r':=\frac{dr}{d\theta}$).

It is a consequence of the (rather classical) formula

$$\tan \psi = \dfrac{r}{r'}\tag{2}$$

where $\psi$ is the (oriented) angle between the radius-vector $OP$ and the tangent at point $P$.

Formula (2) is for example mentionned in the answer by Nosrati to this (interesting) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3035251)

[image]

Now, with the notations you find below in your "augmented" figure :

$$\tan \psi = \tan(\alpha + \pi/2) = - \frac{1}{\tan \alpha} = -\frac{r}{MG}\tag{3}$$

(the last inequality being established in triangle $PMG$).

Setting equality between (2) and (3) gives (1).

**Remark:** The subnormal $MG$ of the curve is indeed $-yy'$ (a classical formula).

**Different questions [in fact answered by having access to the (Google) book of Sir Greenhill named "Applications of elliptic functions"]:**

- You say "the curve that the ellipse describes". Could it be said a stronger property, i.e., "the curve  on which the ellipse is rolling without slipping" (in such a way that its center moves on a horizontal line) ?  [Answer $\to$ yes]
- What is the relationship between parameter $m$ of the elliptic curve  $y=\operatorname{dn}(x,m)$ and the values of $a,b$ ? [Answer $\to$ in fact it is $y = a \operatorname{dn}(x/b,e)$ with $m = e $ (the ellipse's eccentricity)]

[image]

Edit: About the point you are underlining, I see a classical cause of misunderstanding: one should never use the same letter as the integration variable AND an integration bound like here:

$$x=\int_y^{a} \dfrac{ab dy}{\sqrt{(a^2-y^2)(y^2-b^2)}}$$

but INSTEAD write this under the form:

$$x=\int_{Y=y}^{Y=a} \dfrac{ab dY}{\sqrt{(a^2-Y^2)(Y^2-b^2)}}dY$$
where the integration variable (capital) $Y$ is distinguishable from the bound $y$, making the limit case (brough by extremal value $y=b$) much more natural:

$$\int_{Y=b}^{Y=a} \dfrac{ab dY}{\sqrt{(a^2-Y^2)(Y^2-b^2)}}dY$$

Comment: That was the book I also looked at and it was not clear, thank you for explaining it.

Comment: Thank you, reciprocally, for having brought this nice application to our attention. If I have time, I will add a nice grouped representation of functions $cn,sn,dn$. If you don't see it coming, write me !

Comment: I am actually writing my undergrad thesis about Jacobi ellipitc functions, so if you need i can send you some sources which I used and also my thesis(although it is writen in my native language as is my presenetation) if it helps your cause.

Comment: It is slovenian. I have sent you an email, regarding the topic and I hope it helps you.

Comment: It is funny how writting something little differently makes it much clearer, appreciate it.